# How do I display a copyleft symbol?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I use Google AppEngine, Python 2.7 and Jinja2 template. 
I tried this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#Symbol from Wikipedia. As html it prints fine on my browser. But when I insert it in a jinja2 template and try testing it in my GoogleAppEngine app, it gives a 500 Server Error. Here is the screen shot of the stack trace that I got on the log console:

```
ERROR    2013-10-27 18:06:45,460 mycs253app.py:245] []

ERROR    2013-10-27 18:06:45,648 webapp2.py:1528] 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1290: invalid start byte

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\mycs253app.py", line 294, in get

    self.render_front_page(page_no)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\mycs253app.py", line 289, in render_front_page

    self.response.out.write(template.render(page))

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render

    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\templates\main.html", line 1, in top-level template code

    {% extends "base.html" %}

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1290: invalid start byte

ERROR    2013-10-27 18:06:45,677 wsgi.py:278] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle

    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__

    response = self._internal_error(e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\mycs253app.py", line 294, in get

    self.render_front_page(page_no)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\mycs253app.py", line 289, in render_front_page

    self.response.out.write(template.render(page))

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6\jinja2\environment.py", line 894, in render

    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

  File "C:\Users\duck\Documents\GitHub\mycs253app\templates\main.html", line 1, in top-level template code

    {% extends "base.html" %}

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1290: invalid start byte

INFO     2013-10-27 23:36:45,926 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

here's the template that causes the error (the copyleft is at the end):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

  <title>My Blog</title>

</head>

<body>

  <a href="/" class="main-title">
    My Blog
  </a>

  <div class="login-area">
    {% if user %}
      <a class="login-link" href="/newpost" >newpost</a>
      {{user.username}} (<a class="login-link" href="/logout">logout</a>)
    {% else %}
      <a class="login-link" href="/login">login</a>
      |
      <a class="login-link" href="/signup">signup</a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  <div id="content">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>


<!--Copyleft-->

<div style = "color: #333; font-size: 14px" >

<!--[if lte IE 8]><span style="filter: FlipH; -ms-filter: "FlipH"; display: inline-block;"><![endif]-->
<span style="-moz-transform: scaleX(-1); -o-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1); display: inline-block;">
    ©
</span>
<!--[if lte IE 8]></span><![endif]-->

Chintan Pokhrel

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Also, it gives a ?(question mark) symbol when I try to print ɔ (U+0254), but no error.

Comment: Please copy-paste the errors, not post pictures there of.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant part of your template?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid just updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest replacing the copyright symbol `©` in the template with `&copy;`

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked!! but can't vote up, because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

There is only an approximation in Unicode.
Display the [.png file](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20091123082708/bioshock/images/thumb/f/fc/Copyleft.png/240px-Copyleft.png) and resize with  attributes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the symbol directly into the source code, try adding this to the first line of your python file

```
 # coding=utf-8
```

That tells the interpreter the script uses the utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried even this: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- I use jinja2 templating engine

Comment: @Chintan but did you use the copyleft symbol inside a jinja2 template or in your script source code?

Comment: @Chintan I'm guessing you mean this: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` since the markdown make it a bit *italic* :)

Comment: I'm using it inside the template and @Lipis yes, I meant what you said. I was unable to format it that way.

Answer (score 0):

To print the Copyleft symbol in Python, just do this:

```py
>>> print('\U0001f12f')
```

Regards.